# Web based email client for postfix

Tags: email, postfix

I decided to run a self hosted email server for fun. I installed and setup Postfix and S-Nail on a Ubuntu VM. Everything works perfectly and I can send and receive emails. Now that I got that done I would like to make it were I don't have to SSH into the VM to send mail. Are there any web based email clients that will work on a Maildir? As far as I can tell SquirrelMail and Roundcube require IMAP or POP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any web based email clients that will work on a Maildir?

While they do *exist,* it's very rare to find one. The Courier mail software (which I believe invented Maildir?) used to have SqWebMail, which I last used in 2010 and it was kind of garbage even back then – and that's the **only** direct-Maildir web client that I've seen so far.

Even for a single-user system, it will be simpler for you to set up some kind of IMAP access. Dovecot is rather simple to set up and will read your Maildir out of the box; there will be fewer file permission issues (please resist the temptation to give www-data full read access to everyone's Maildirs).

Answer (score 0):

Postfix is an MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) so it only handles sending/receiving email from other MTAs, eg it only handles the SMTP part of the email process. It doesn't handle POP3, IMAP or mailboxes.

For that you need to install something like Dovecot as well to handle those elements, before adding RoundCube or similar to add webmail functionality to that pairing.

Essentially, rather than having one app or service that handles everything, when not everyone NEEDS everything (you could potentially have a server only running Postfix, which relays email elsewhere, so never needs POP3/IMAP/Webmail functionality), you have a collection of email services that work together to do what you need.

There are various guides online to installing the trio to work together, for instance https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-postfix-dovecot-and-roundcube-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: You are mostly right, but Postfix CAN write to mailboxes and maildirs.    Also, Postfix is extremely flexible and uses pipes, so while it does not do POP3 or IMAP natively it is designed to handle lots of parts of the mail process outside of SMTP.  (eg virus checking, spam checking, redirection)